# animate text color jquery - shift between two colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

it is such that I must have my text in my to flash back and forth between #ff9900 and blue, so if you hold the mouse over the text so it only needs to be white and it should not change color or anything else.

The problem is: It will not start when it is, that I think of it to start by itself.

Would it work to change color back and forth between #ff9900 and blue, and if you hold the mouse over so it stops but then the white words text.

```
 $(".frivilligBox a").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).animate({
       color: '#333'
     }, 600);
});

$(".frivilligBox a").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).animate({
      color: '#666'
   }, 600);
});
```

It is with that I have written a different color here, it was more just to see if it works.

To which I would really like it was something in this quiet, just background was text in the presence of all color, as will be shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/wn8kJ/3/

My looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uF292/

Comment: You'll have to include jQuery UI or a color plugin to animate colors ?

Comment: @adeneo i have include "`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`"

Comment: @adeneo are you here?